# Handling Multipart request that is not an Action request?

Tags: spring-mvc, request, portlet, multipart

I've been thinking if it is possible to handle Multipart request that is not an Action request. There is a reason why it seems impossible to me :

> Only ActionRequest implements
>   getFile() kind of methods. I can't
>   find any easy way how to get the file
>   out of request other than Action
>   request

What if I don't use a html form to upload a file and I don't want a view to be rendered after action request - render phase happens always after the action phase.

What if I want to create a post request (with file(s)) by ajax and use @ResourceMapping handler. How do I get it out of ResourceRequest ?

Thank you very much for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "pattern" that is afaik the best way of handling Multipart requests

Action request from view layer goes to this method:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "javax.portlet.action=sample")
public void response(MultipartActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
    response.setRenderParameter("javax.portlet.action", "success");
    List<MultipartFile> fileList = request.getFiles("file");
}
```

render phase follows :

```
@RequestMapping(params = "javax.portlet.action=success")
public ModelAndView process(RenderRequest request, Model model) throws IOException {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("test", new Integer(1));
    return new ModelAndView("someView", map);
}
```

You create a "bean" view :

```
@Component("someView")
public class SomeView extends AbstractView {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeView.class);

    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map map, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
    logger.info("Resolving ajax request view - " + map);
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(map);
    logger.info("content Type = " + getContentType());
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(jsonObj.toString());
    response.getWriter().flush();
    }
}
```

You add BeanNameViewResolver into your servlet/portlet context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="1" />
```

Comment: Hi lisak, thank you for your pattern. But I do not understand how the ModelAndView is picked up by BeanNameViewResolver - and not the global InternalResourceViewResolver. And in my test, I can't get the part out of MultipartActionRequest. Thank you of your explanations. Philippe